# Calculate object with highest value property in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multilayered array in which I want to calculate the object which contains the highest value of a specific property.

```
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    card: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        info: {
            age: 36,
            height: 152
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    card: {
        firstName: 'Dan',
        lastName: 'Hislop',
        info: {
            age: 38,
            height: 155
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 3,
    card: {
        firstName: 'Mary',
        lastName: 'Walter',
        info: {
            age: 29,
            height: 122
        }
    }
}]
```

I want to be able to calculate the top level object in that array that contains the highest `age` value, and returns that object.

The best I can do at the moment is find the highest value and return that value alone:

```
let oldest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(obj =>
  obj.card.info.age) )
```

But I want the whole object.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.card.info.age < curr.card.info.age ? curr : prev)
```

Nothing magical about it, we just look at two objects at a time and continue with the one which has the higher age.

Comment: reduce, reduce, reduce all the time... Of course you can do everything with reduce, almost everything a good old for loop can do, not more. It looks like there is something magical behind reduce, this is annoying x-)

Comment: No it is not. The answer he got from @Pranav C Balan is.

reduce is an overkill.

Comment: This reduce just compares two objects and returns the one with the higher age. The comment by Pranav returns the max value, not the object, but we need the object. I find apply harder to read than reduce.

Answer (score 1):

A good old for loop looks perfect to me :

```js
var i, xs, max;
xs = [{value:3},{value:1},{value:4},{value:2}];
for (i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0 || xs[i].value > xs[max].value) {
    max = i;
  }
}
console.log(xs[max]);
```